# Condition Number of Polynomial (Condition Number = 0)

Tags: matrices, polynomials, numerical-methods

I'm calculating the condition number of a polynomial equation

$$ 
y = (x-2)^{9}
$$

for this equation, the `Jacobian` is equal to `0`, thus the condition number is equal to `0` .

my question is, does this imply that the matrix is perfectly conditioned? I made a plot of the polynomial and for some ball of values of x sufficiently close to `x = 2`, the derivative stays small-- on the order of e-3 -- which leads me to believe that the polynomial is backwards stable.

additionally, would this imply that for any large order polynomial, the algo is backwards stable for a proportionally large ball of values near the root?

Answer (score 2):

The condition number for the $j$ th root and $i$ th coefficient is $\kappa=$$\dfrac{\mid a_{i}x_{j}^{i-1}\mid}{{\mid p\prime(x_{j})\mid}}$, since you have known all the coefficients of the polynomial, you can calculate each number close to $2$ repect to the each coefficient to determine whether is a well-condition or an ill-condition.